# android programming - tabs won't work

Tags: android, eclipse, tabs

I'm a new user and a beginner android programmer. I've written a code in MainActivity.java, which won't work on the virtual device, and I don't know the reason. Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work?
thanks in advance

```
package com.tee.contactsList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    LinearLayout mainLayout;
    TextView title;
    TextView contact1;
    ScrollView scrollList;
    LinearLayout list;
    TabHost tabs;
    TabSpec firstTab;
    TabSpec secondTab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tabs = new TabHost(this); 
        firstTab = tabs.newTabSpec("tid1");
        secondTab = tabs.newTabSpec("tid2");
        mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        title = new TextView(this);
        contact1 = new TextView(this);
        scrollList = new ScrollView(this);
        list = new LinearLayout(this);
        tabs.addTab(firstTab);
        tabs.addTab(secondTab);
        firstTab.setIndicator("Contacts");
        secondTab.setIndicator("Calender");
        tabs.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(1);
        mainLayout.setId(123);
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        list.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        mainLayout.addView(title);
        title.setText("Contacts");
        mainLayout.addView(scrollList);
        scrollList.addView(list);
        scrollList.setBackgroundColor(0x0000ff00);
        list.setBackgroundColor(0x0000ff00);
        contact1.setBackgroundColor(0x0000ff00);
        list.addView(contact1);
        String s="\n";
        String array[]={"contact1","contact2","contact3","contact4","contact5"};
        for (int x=0;x<=4;x++)
        {
            s+="contact";
            s+=(x+1);
            s+=":";
            s+=array[x];
            s+="\n";
        }
        contact1.setText(s);
        firstTab.setContent(123);
        setContentView(tabs);
    }
```

}

Comment: how exactly is it "not working"? Your code doesn't actually do very much, does it?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What do you get and what do you expect to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create your layout as an xml.

in the activity you refer to the viewIDs of the elements that you created in the xml -> findviewbyid

obejcts are only created in your code, they are not assigned to a layout.
the same happens with setContentView for example. A viewID is expected there
r.layout.xml_file